# JsonArrayRequest in volley not sending params , though the same code ran in my other application

Tags: android, json, android-volley

Given below is the code to send parameter to my sever side code using Volley but it is not sending though the same code ran successfully at my previous mobile app..

Please assist

Given below is the code to send parameter to my sever side code using `Volley` but it is not sending though the same code ran successfully at my previous mobile app..

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest;

```
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("phone_no",mob_no.getText().toString().trim()+"");


    jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, "URL HERE",new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {



                    }catch (JSONException e)
                    {


                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                }
            }
    ) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("User-Agent","Authorize_bot_send_OTP");

            return headers;
        }


    };

    jsonArrayRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            5000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    ));

    ZeeSingleton.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestque(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: does your `logcat` shows any error ,post that?